# Accessing Arrays in Javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, object

[image: $scope.showbroadcast CONSOLE.LOG]

i'm having trouble accessing `PayLoad`. and i'm not sure if the way that i'm accessing it is the right way. i want to access `PayLoad` and what i did was this:

`console.log("$scope.showbroadcast::", $scope.showbroadcast][0].PayLoad);`

how should i access that kind of data (as shown on the picture).

Comment: console.log("$scope.showbroadcast::", $scope.showbroadcast][0].PayLoad['data']['txtno']);

Comment: you have to use index of each elements like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(function() {})
  .controller('MyAppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = "John";

    //this array is comes from your api endpoint or any project  file
    $scope.array = {
      "myarray": [{
        "FinalName": "john lloyd",
        "Message": "hi",
        "Name": "john lloyd",
        "PayLoad": {
          "data": {
            "txnno": "790....",
            "subject": "BROADCAST"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "FinalName": "john miller",
        "Message": "hi",
        "Name": "john miller",
        "PayLoad": {
          "data": {
            "txnno": "990....", 
            "subject": "TELECAST" 
          }
        }
      }]
    };


    //If your array contains "N" elements then you have to use foreach or for loop on "myayyay" variable
    $scope.array.myarray.forEach(function(i) {
      console.log('txnno[i]:' + i.PayLoad.data.txnno);
      console.log('subject[i]:' + i.PayLoad.data.subject);
    })


    //If your array contains only one element and you want PayLoad object then
    $scope.payload = $scope.array.myarray[0].PayLoad;
    console.log($scope.payload)

    //If you want to read data inside PayLoad object then
    $scope.txnno = $scope.array.myarray[0].PayLoad.data.txnno;
    $scope.subject = $scope.array.myarray[0].PayLoad.data.subject;
    console.log($scope.txnno)
    console.log($scope.subject)
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller = "MyAppCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    
    <p>txnno: {{txnno}}</p>
    <p>subject: {{subject}}</p>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document).ready(function () { angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']); });
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

I also create a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/7D7nM1nVqzDeVSDEzjUf/) for your better understanding that how you can get "PayLoad" object from array as well "data" inside payload object

I tried to make plunker as simple as possible so that beginners will get clear solution within their knowledge area.

Answer (score 1):

Payload data is in JSON string format, so first convert it into JSON object

$scope.broadcast =angular.fromJson($scope.showbroadcast][0].PayLoad)
then you can access the values from it as:
$scope.txnno = $scope.broadcast.data.txnno